# Form Insertion restriction

Tags: web-services, apache, web, apache2, web-hosting

We have several web sites hosted on a single server.  Recently we found an error, when we tried to enter the word “exit” in any HTML form, we couldn’t do it on any site hosted on the server. Not even the word “exit” if we tried to enter the word “complexity” we couldn’t insert that also because it has got the word “exit” as a part of it. We have tried this on a static html form directed to itself; on that form also we got the same error message “Forbidden 403”. We think this should be an apache web server issue.  But we cannot find the solution. If anyone has experienced this before please let me know. Thanks